# How to write a server using existing version and wireshark?

Tags: python, networking, tcp, wireshark

I decided to improve my knowledge about python network programming and here is the deal: I have a simple server for Windows, which interacts with a client from a mobile device using wi-fi. Also I have a packet sniffer (Wireshark).
Now I want to ask, what do I need to write the Linux version of this server? How to determine the structure of packets, establish the connection? What do I need to use - sockets, Twisted, maybe Tornado?

Answer (score 1):

Start with the [SocketServer](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html) module and build from there.

Note that this will take a lot of guesswork if there is no documentation about the protocol. If you're lucky, they are using XML or HTML. If not, you will have to make the existing server send a lot of test data which you have to manipulate in some way (by changing fields and see what changes in the data stream).

Good luck!